# Transversing through a queue data structure in C# without dequeuing it

Tags: c#

Is there any way to transverse through all the elements of a queue without using dequeue function. i.e. without removing it elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Queue<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` so you can use `foreach`:

```
foreach(T item in queue)
{
}
```